# How to remove emojis and special character from text?

Tags: python, string

I have a text file in this format:

```
 name; country
 Dr Gérald KIERZEK⚡‍⚕️  ; FR
 ⭐️ Le Charmeur™  ;
 * Coach Carter * ; ES
  Acid Girl \*w*/  ; FR
```

I want to remove from each line the emojis and the special character i.e. I want to get in the output only the names without the ID, the country, emojis, special character like `\*w*/`, `™`, `*` ….

Thank you very much

Comment: @Wiktor I don’t think this is an appropriate duplicate: OP wants to not only remove special characters but also more complex “ASCII art” combinations. The linked answers don’t handle `\*w*/`, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
with open("file.txt", "w") as myFile:
  re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', myFile)
```

Comment: thank  you but, it doesn't work

Comment: it works like this  : re.sub('\W+', ' ', str(name_with_emoji)) 
thank you very much

Comment: space would be nice to keep

Comment: @akhbarsers No, that doesn’t work on the input posted in your question. Try it on `'Acid Girl \*w*/'`, for example.